# Firefox webRTC screenshare enable flags via code

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, webrtc, screensharing

I am trying this test https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html for firefox webRTC screenshare.
It requires following in about:config

> media.getusermedia.screensharing.enabled

to be true and domain name to be added in

> media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains

There is one way to do this: change prefs.js file in mozilla user profile. But I don't want to do that. Is there any other way like an extension (chrome provides this) to accomplish this task via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. You have to build an extension to add your domain name in allowed_domains. Steps for extension are [here](https://github.com/opentok/screensharing-extensions/tree/master/firefox)